# Primefaces 5.3 charts freezes in chrome59 when exporting as image

Tags: primefaces

We are using Primefaces v5.3. We are trying to export charts generated by primefaces(jqplot) through exportAsImage function:

function generateImage(chartId) {

```
            var img = PF(chartId).exportAsImage();
            $('#form\\:' + chartId + "-image").val($(img).attr("src"));
        }
```

In other browsers(IE and firefox) charts are displaying correctly. This happens only in chorome 59 other versions it's working fine.

After analysing I found that continous loop is happening in exportAsImage().

How to fix this issue in chrome59.

Comment: Update chrome? Update PrimeFaces? And the export is a jqplot issue as can be read other posts

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already updated chrome latest version, Primefaces i'm using 5.3. I understood that it is jqplot issue. But is there any way to fix this issue.